# Array in function- wrong value

Tags: php

I'm sending 3 arrays with all arguments equal to 1. So the output of 'd' should be 9 and 'n' also ought to be 9. Instead I get 39. Anyone knows why?
This is function

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
function eq1($a,$b,$c)
{
 $d= $a[0]*$b[1]*$c[2]+$b[0]*$c[1]*$a[2]+$c[0]*$a[1]*$b[2];
 $n= $c[0]*$b[1]*$a[2]+$b[0]*$a[1]*$c[2]+$a[0]*$c[1]*$b[2];
echo $d;
echo $n;

}
?> 
</body>
</html>
```

This is example of array definition
`$a= [1,1,1]`;
`$b= [1,1,1]`;
`$c= [1,1,1]`;

This is calling for fuction

```
//calculating for cramer method 
$dg=eq1($a,$b,$c);
```

Comment: Let's put it this way: if indeed all your values are `1`, and you're really just doing a whole bunch of `1*1+1*1...`, then obviously there should be absolutely no difference. Hence, the only explanation is that there *is* a difference in your input. So... you'll have to provide us a *complete, self contained example* which we can run to reproduce your problem. At the moment we just have screenshots of disconnected snippets...

Comment: You values cannot be all `1`s because it would be a mathematical impossibility that both your equations give different results. The only explanation is that your input is different at some point.

Comment: Ok I edited post, I hope it helps.

Comment: **[Cannot reproduce](https://3v4l.org/ORa90)**, as expected.

Answer (score -1):

kubauser you've only echoed the '$d' and the '$n' variables, you want the function to return the value hence use the "return" keyword, otherwise it might return a random number or so...

The syntax is as follows:

```
<?php
    function func($a,$b)
    {
      $c = $a +$b;
      return $c;
    }

    echo func(3,5);
<?
```

Comment: kubauser an array in php is initialized thusly,

Comment: $a = array(1,1,1);